# Fetching saved data from parse webservice?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, web-services, parse-platform

I am using Parse webservice in my iphone app.
I can save and retrieve the data in my account.

I am fetching saved data as below -

```
   -(void)Fetch{

      PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Gossips"];
      [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
       [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSArray* wallObjectsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        NSLog(@"wallObjectsArray:--------- %@", wallObjectsArray);

     } else {
        NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorString);
       }
   }];
    }
```

and the out put -

```
    wallObjectsArray:--------- "<MyApp:dPotrdMmZy> {\n    category = politics;\n    content = \"Madiba died..!!\";\n    user = john;\n}",
```

How can I retrieve each object for different keys from this array.
I want to find out waht is content and who is user ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (PFObject *innerObject in objects)
{ 
  NSLog(@"WallObjects:------ %@", innerObject);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simply added "for" loop to get the info you wanted with some sample "UserName" and "Score" field which needs to be changed to whats in you parse.com class.

Hope it helps

```
-(void)Fetch{
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Gossips"];  
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
          //  NSArray* wallObjectsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
         //   NSLog(@"wallObjectsArray:--------- %@", wallObjectsArray);

            for (PFObject *info in objects) {

                NSLog(@"Id: %@", info.objectId);
                NSLog(@"User: Name %@", [info objectForKey:@"UserName"]);
                NSLog(@"Score: %@", [info objectForKey:@"Score"]);
            }
        } else {
            NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorString);
        }
    }];

}
```